# Is there a way to append in a 2d array without numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So, my computer won't load `numpy` and I need to append another row to a 2d array with 7 rows. Is there a way to append another row?

I've already tried `a.append` but it doesn't work because there are multiple rows.

```
a = ([['Mon', 18, 20, 22, 17], 
     ['Tue', 11, 18, 21, 18],
     ['Wed', 15, 21, 20, 19], 
     ['Thu', 11, 20, 22, 21],
     ['Fri', 18, 17, 23, 22], 
     ['Sat', 12, 22, 20, 18],
     ['Sun', 13, 15, 19, 16]])

for elem in a:
        print(elem)

m_r = append(a, [['Avg', 12, 15, 13, 11]], 0)
```

I want to have another row of `[['Avg', 12, 15, 13, 11]], 0)` underneath the rest of my code, but I'm only getting errors.

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code.

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question. We can't run it and we can't see your monitor so we can't see error.

Comment: you mean `a.append(['Avg', 12, 15, 13, 11])`

Comment: Are those backticks actually part of your code? Or is that supposed to be for code block formatting?

Comment: Here it makes more sense to think of `a` as a list that contains lists.  You just want to add a new list to that outer list.  That's a simple list append.

Answer (score 1):

`append` should normally work in this case. Try:

```
a.append(['Avg', 12, 15, 13, 11])
```

The problem might be the double bracket `[[`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a list of lists, which you think of as a "2d array". To add another "row", simply use append, e.g. `a.append(['Avg', 12, 15, 13, 11])`.